# Resizing canvas causes drawing to become blurry

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a signature pad for a customer. I put a small canvas under a button that makes the canvas bigger.

When I draw on the small canvas and then make it bigger it's fine, but if I draw on the big canvas and then make it smaller it makes the drawing very blurry. This is the option I need to work because when the customer signs it needs to be a big canvas and after its shows it in an 'Order' PDF so it needs to be small

What can I do?

```js
var signatureDataUrl = null;

// Function to capture the signature as an image.
function captureSignature(canvas) {
  const scaleFactor = 2; // Adjust the scale factor as needed
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor); // Scale up the canvas context
  signatureDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0); // Capture at maximum quality
}

// Function to redraw the signature after resizing.
function redrawSignature(canvas) {
  if (signatureDataUrl) {
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      // Clear the canvas before redrawing
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      // Draw the image on the canvas at the original size
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    };
    image.src = signatureDataUrl;
  }
}

// Function to toggle canvas size.
function toggleCanvasSize(canvas, toggleButton) {
  // Save the current signature before resizing
  captureSignature(canvas);
  if (!canvas.classList.contains('fullscreen')) {
    // Make the canvas full screen
    const originalWidth = canvas.width;
    const originalHeight = canvas.height;
    const aspectRatio = originalWidth / originalHeight;
    const newWidth = window.innerWidth - 10; // Subtract 10px for left and right margins
    const newHeight = newWidth / aspectRatio;
    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;
    canvas.style.marginRight = "-375px";
    canvas.classList.add('fullscreen');
    // Change button text to 'הקטן' and class to 'uk-button-danger'
    toggleButton.textContent = 'הקטן';
    toggleButton.classList.remove('uk-button-success');
    toggleButton.classList.add('uk-button-danger');
  } else {
    // Restore the original canvas size
    canvas.width = 302; // Set to original width
    canvas.height = 122; // Set to original height
    canvas.style.marginRight = ''; // Removes the marginRight style
    canvas.style.marginLeft = ''; // Removes the marginLeft style
    canvas.style.display = ''; // Resets display to the default value
    canvas.classList.remove('fullscreen');
    // Change button text to 'הגדל' and class to 'uk-button-success'
    toggleButton.textContent = 'הגדל';
    toggleButton.classList.remove('uk-button-danger');
    toggleButton.classList.add('uk-button-success');
  }
  // Redraw the signature after resizing
  redrawSignature(canvas);
}

// Get The Correct Canvas And Button
function getOrderBodyCanvas() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas[name="orderBody"]');
  const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggleSizeOrderBody');
  toggleCanvasSize(canvas, toggleButton)
}

function getInstallationPricingCanvas() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas[name="installationpricing"]');
  const toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggleSizeInstallationPricing');
  toggleCanvasSize(canvas, toggleButton)
}

//Clear Canvas
function clearCanvas(canvas) {
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// On Click Events On the Toggle Size Buttons
document.getElementById('toggleSizeOrderBody').addEventListener('click', getOrderBodyCanvas);
document.getElementById('toggleSizeInstallationPricing').addEventListener('click', getInstallationPricingCanvas);
document.getElementById('clearCanvasOrderBody').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas[name="orderBody"]');
  if (canvas) {
    clearCanvas(canvas);
  }
});

document.getElementById('clearCanvasInstallationPricing').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas[name="installationpricing"]');
  if (canvas) {
    clearCanvas(canvas);
  }
});
```

Comment: The context's transform matrix has no incidence whatsoever on `canvas.toDataURL()`, the image extracted by this method is still only as big as the canvas it's been called on. So if when you save the signature your canvas is only 302x122 you only have a 302x122 png image and drawing it bigger will indeed look blurry. How is that "signature" produced originally? If it's by recording the user's pointer movement, then save the coordinates instead of saving a png image, this way you can redraw at whatever scale you like.

Answer (score 0):

The blurriness could be due to loss of canvas resolution loss while resizing the canvas context.
You can resolve this issue by resizing the canvas element instead of canvas context.
Try the code below to fix that issue.

```js
function toggleCanvasSize(canvas, toggleButton) {
  captureSignature(canvas);
  if (!canvas.classList.contains('fullscreen')) {
    canvas.classList.add('fullscreen');
    toggleButton.textContent = 'הקטן';
    toggleButton.classList.remove('uk-button-success');
    toggleButton.classList.add('uk-button-danger');
  } else {
    canvas.classList.remove('fullscreen');
    toggleButton.textContent = 'הגדל';
    toggleButton.classList.remove('uk-button-danger');
    toggleButton.classList.add('uk-button-success');
  }
  redrawSignature(canvas);
}
```